# Redirect 404 error with Prettyfaces 3.3.X and JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

I want to redirect all 404 errors to a custom url with prettyfaces.
I try a lot of thing but i can't find the right solution to my case (despite the lot of post about this)

Here some informations

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- JSF configuration
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->    
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>    

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- PrettyFaces configuration
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->    
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.ocpsoft.pretty.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.ocpsoft.pretty.BASE_PACKAGES</param-name>
    <param-value>com.lagoon.project.web</param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- Server configuration
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>404</exception-type>
    <location>/page-introuvable</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

under Web Pages\modules\website

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>404</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the bean

```
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;


@RequestScoped
@URLMapping(id = "pageWebSitePageNotfound", pattern = "/page-introuvable", viewId = "/modules/website/pageNotFound.xhtml")
@ManagedBean(name = "pageWebSitePageNotfound")
public class PageWebSitePageNotfound {

}
```

and the pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.lagoon</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>project</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <jsf.version>2.2.8-02</jsf.version>    
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>            
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    - Web
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    - Misc
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

When i try "/page-introuvable" JSF show me the page... but if i try "/somethingElse" I just have a standard 404 error from my navigator

How can i do ?

thanks

Answer (score -2):

In your web.xml set this block of cody

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404page.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

It will intercept any 404 error and will redirect the page to the another page, you define the page at `<location>/404page.xhtml</location>`.

Comment: Please edit your [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28726027) instead of posting a new one.